# MongoDB Check if a Collection contains a Key

Tags: mongodb

I am using the MongoDB Async Driver to create a little Program were i have to save a User-Profile in the Database. 
So i have a Database looking like this

```html
 `{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1743f086060f1bbc319cdb"), 
    "id" : "aUser1", 
    "SomeArray" : {
        "Name" : "SomeName"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1743f186060f1bbc319cdc"), 
    "id" : "aUser2", 
    "SomeArray" : {
        "Name" : "SomeName"
    }
}
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a1743f286060f1bbc319cdd"), 
    "id" : "aUser3", 
    "SomeArray" : {
        "Name" : "SomeName"
    }
}`
```

And now i try to figure out if the User 1 already has created a Profile.
Whith the old driver i would know how but with the , for me new, Async-Driver it sems a little bit tricky, do i have to make an Callback for this ?

Comment: Did you read about creating index with unique value in mongoDB?